# HttpURLConnection always failing with 401

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to use HttpURLConnection for connecting to server from Android app which I'm developing. For now, I'm testing the connection code not in an app but as a plain java program with main class. I guess this doesn't make any difference as far as HttpUrlConnection.

Please examine the code snippet. Another issue is even errorStream is throwing null. This I feel is because of malformed URL.

```
private static String urlConnectionTry() {
URL url; HttpURLConnection connection = null;

try {
    String urlParameters = "email=" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") +
            "&pwd=" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8");
    //Create connection
    url = new URL("http://example.com/login");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("uuid", getUuid());
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
            connection.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
    wr.flush ();
    wr.close ();

    //Get Response
    InputStream is = connection.getErrorStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    return response.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} finally {
    if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

```
private static String getUuid() {
try {
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/getUuid").get();
    Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");
    for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
        if(metaElem.attr("name").equals("uuid")) {
            return metaElem.attr("content");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're probably receiving 401 because the credentials that was sent to the server is not authorized- it's probably not registered or the password is incorrect.

As for the null error stream, take a look at this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070350/errorstream-in-httpurlconnection).

> If the connection was not connected, or if the server did not have an error while connecting or if the server had an error but no error data was sent, this method will return null.

It is probably better if you check first the response code using `HttpUrlConnection#getResponseCode()`. Decide on whether you'll be checking the contents of the error stream based on the response code you get.